# Connecting to Azure AD api using graph with an WPF application

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to use graph to connect to an azure AD in an wpf application. Authentication seems to go ok and I get an access token returned. I can also use this token to get basic info about myself. However when I try to request something from the directory I get the error:

> Code":"JWT10315 Signature validation failed. Keys tried:

And then a whole bunch of other stuff. All seems to be ok. The app is registered in Azure. I have the correct access permissions set. I'm clueless. Anyone who can help me along? My code is below.

```
//using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace O365_Graph_Connector
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //graph endpoint
    //$upn="userPrincipalName eq '" + $user.Id +"'"
    string url = "https://graph.windows.net/mydomain.com/activities/signinEvents?api-version=beta&`$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'upn@withheld.com'";
    //string url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/";
    //Scopes
    string[] _scopes = new string[] { "Directory.Read.All" };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtOutput.Text = "bla";


    }

    private async void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

        try
        {
            if (authResult == null)
            {
                authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
                Console.WriteLine("authenticated");
            }
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("trying method2");
                authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(_scopes);

            }
            catch (MsalException msalex)
            {
                txtOutput.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
            return;
        }

        if (authResult != null)
        {
            //txtOutput.Text = await GetHttpContentWithToken(url, authResult.AccessToken);
            String strResult = await GetHttpContentWithToken(url, authResult.AccessToken);
            txtOutput.Text = strResult;

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Perform an HTTP GET request to a URL using an HTTP Authorization header
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL</param>
    /// <param name="token">The token</param>
    /// <returns>String containing the results of the GET operation</returns>
    public async Task<string> GetHttpContentWithToken(string url, string token)
    {
        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
            //Add the token in Authorization header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnSignOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (App.PublicClientApp.Users.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                App.PublicClientApp.Remove(App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
                this.txtOutput.Text = "User has signed-out";
                //this.CallGraphButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                //this.SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                txtOutput.Text = $"Error signing-out user: {ex.Message}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> string url = "https://graph.windows.net/mydomain.com/activities/signinEvents?api-version=beta&`$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'upn@withheld.com'";

According to your description, you are accessing [Azure Active Directory sign-in activity report API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-sign-in-activity-reference). I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-prerequisites-azure-portal) to check this issue. I both checked the **App-only scopes** (apps run as a service without a signed-in user) and **delegated scopes** (delegate the privileges of the signed-in user) with the **Directory.Read.All** scope, and I could also retrieve the user's information.

But when I access the sign-in activity API Endpoint via postman with the access token, I got a response and prompt me to upgrade my tenant to Azure AD Premium tier, then I pick up my directory and activate the trial by click "Company branding > Get Free Premium Trial" on azure portal. Upon the upgrade, I could retrieve the sign-in activity as follows:

[image]

Additionally, I encountered the similar issue as follows:

[image]

In general, you could leverage [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to decode your access token and make sure the related properties have been correctly contained.

Comment: I have the excat error message in your last screenshot. When I use powershell it works. So it seems the powershell variant works differently as the wpf variant. IT also has something to do with the graph api I try to access. Most others work. IT is just this one generating the error. I'm a bit at a loss here. Someone has an example with working code that accesses the azureAD API through a WPF app? I'm at a loss what to do here. We have azureAD premium

Comment: I got the above error when the appid from the decoded access token does not match the one under my tenant. I would recommend you using postman  to simulate the request against sign-in activity api with your access token to narrow this issue.

Comment: Since the powershell could work, you could trace the network and compare with your application via fiddler.